# IE thinks that float initial is float left?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following html :

```
<div class="cleanContainer"> 
    <div style="height:80px">test</div>
</div>
```

And this CSS :

```
.cleanContainer
{
    float:                      left;
    padding:                    7px;
    background-color:           #ffffff;
    width:                      786px;
    -moz-border-radius:         2px 2px 2px 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:      2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-radius:              2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

Then I got a @media screen CSS file where I got this :

```
.cleanContainer
{
    float:                      initial;
    padding:                    3px;
    width:                      auto;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, the float is set to none and will take the entire width. In IE it will be set as `float: left` and this is no good for the design?

How do I solve this?

EDIT : here is a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/ahCga/2/

Comment: Why don't you use `float:none` instead?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `float:initial`. Is that a valid value for `float`?

Comment: "initial" is not a valid float value. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: For those people who think that "initial" is not a valid float value, [css3-values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#component-types) says: "All CSS properties also accept the CSS-wide keyword values as the sole component of their property value. For readability these are not listed explicitly in the property value syntax definitions. For example, the full value definition of ‘border-color’ is ‘[ <color>{1,4} ] | inherit | initial’ (even though it is listed as ‘<color>{1,4}’)."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Alochi found the initial value on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords so the OP was not wrong in the view but this is not implemented yet for all the browsers.

So,

Use `float: none;` instead of `float: initial;`

There is no such value for float property yet compatible. [See here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float)

```
Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Values            |  left   |    right     |     none    |   inherit
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Initial value     |  none  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Applies to        |  All element
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Inherited         |  No
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Values are specified by w3.org:

**left**

> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top.

**right**

> Similar to 'left', except the box is floated to the right, and content flows on the left side of the box, starting at the top.

**none**

> The box is not floated.

**inherit**

> Takes the same specified value as the property for the element's parent.

Comment: good find but did you noticed this is as of CSS Values and Units Module Level 3

Comment: Sure. I knew it was in CSS3 somewhere, but I had to have rummage through the various CSS3 specs to find out which one.

Answer (score 4):

As I was saying in my Comment..

you can see <kbd>[**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)</kbd>
that `float` as `none` as the initial value.
and the available options are

1. float: left
2. float: right
3. float: none
4. float: inherit

so use `float: none` instead of `float:initial`

Chrome works only because hes trying to be nice with you.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.cleanContainer
{
    float:none;
    padding:3px;
    width:auto;
}
```

There is no "float:initial" in CSS specification, "initial" means default state which is "none".